# Lista de objetos volta zerada da View mesmo com Hiddenfield

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, lista

```
 public ComprasOrdemCompras GetToCreate(ComprasOrdemCompras model, int EmpresaId)
        {
            ComprasOrdemComprasProduto clsPedidoProduto = new ComprasOrdemComprasProduto();
            //Preenchi meu produto INÍCIO
            // FIM
            model.ListaPedidosProdutos.Add(clsPedidoProduto);
            return model;
        }
```

Após realizar um foreach ou for preenchendo a lista visualmente na View, ao tentar inserir  um novo item na lista a mesma volta zerada, no código acima apenas resumi, na View deixei também um hiddenfield mas a lista mesmo assim retorna zerada no parâmetro. Oque faço?

Código da View resumido:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "OrdemCompras", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary()
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ListaPedidosProdutos)

     @for (int i = 0; i < Model.ListaPedidosProdutos.Count; i++ )
     {
         <tr>
             <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.ListaPedidosProdutos[i].ProdutoEmpresaId)</td>
             @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ListaPedidosProdutos[i].ProdutoEmpresaId)

             <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.ListaPedidosProdutos[i].ProdutoNome)</td>

         </tr>
      }
```

Comment: Você pode postar o código da View também, por favor?

Comment: Pronto, coloquei resumidamente o código da view

Comment: Já consegui a solução, obrigado. Reeditei com a correção.

Comment: Ah sim, com certeza, eu editei pois não consegui responder minha própria pergunta, tentarei responder mais tarde.

Answer (score 1):

Resolvido! é necessário retirar a linha :

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ListaPedidosProdutos)
```

pois já existe um hidden que acessa dentro da Lista em:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ListaPedidosProdutos[i].ProdutoEmpresaId)
```

Obrigado.